# What causes this failure to compile SCSS to CSS with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

I am working on a project that needs CSS and JavaScript code to be compiled in distinct files.

I have a JavaScript source file - `<root>/src/js/main.js` - that is compiled into `<root>/dist/main.js`, as expected.

The webpack config file looks like so:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
mode: 'development',
entry: "./src/js/main.js",
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: "/dist"
 },
  watch:true,
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.s?css$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader"
          ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css",
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
      })
  ]
}
```

In `<root>/src/scss/` I have an `app.scss` file with various imports:

```
// Fonts
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito');

// Bootstrap 4
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

// Layout
@import './layout';
```

##### The *directories and files* tree:

[image]

The `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.50.0",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

#### The problem:

I need the **SCSS** to be compiled into `<root>/dist/css/app.css`, but something must be missing from the `webpack.config.js` file because no CSS file is generated.

#### Questions:

1. What is missing from the config file?
2. How can I make sure the generated CSS is minified?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible version of your code?

Comment: @nyedidikeke There is something missing from the `webpack.config.js`  (all the code it contains is in the snippet).

Comment: You may have missed to import your root scss file in your js entry point file. This would cause it to never be processed.

Comment: @Martin How should I do that?

Comment: Your entry file is `./src/js/main.js`, add an import statement for your root scss file there `import '../scss/app.scss';`

Comment: @Martin It does not work. I need the SCSS files in `src\scss` to be compiled in `dist\css\app.css`.

Comment: Yes, but webpack needs to know which files are to be processed. and it does so by starting at the entry point and processing everything that is imported there, and does this recursively for all imported files. If you don't import it in your js it will not be processed.

Comment: What does the import statement of `app.scss` look like and what file is it in?

Comment: @morganney In `src\js\main.js` I added `import '../scss/app.scss'` according to the indications of @Martin. It throws an error.

Comment: Did you want to share the details of the error?

Comment: @morganney ` // Exports
48 | /* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = (___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___);
49 |
 @ ./src/js/main.js 1:0-26` says the terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### css bundling

Basically your css is not bundled cause webpack is configruated to build only `./src/js/main.js` file and all the other files that are imported from that single entry point.

To make webpack bundle css files you can either import it from handled js files or include it as additional `entryPoint` into `webpack.config.js`:

###### Option 1. Add import

Just add into `src/js/main.js` file the following line

```js
import "../scss/app.scss";
```

###### Option 2. Specify entry point in webpack config

Remove current entry point line

```
entry: "./src/js/main.js",
```

And add new entry point line with multiple entry points specified

```
entry: ["./src/js/main.js", "./src/scss/app.scss"],
```

#### output files structure

In your question you mentioned that you want to put js bundle to `./dist/js/main.js` and css bundle to `./dist/css/app.css` but webpack is not very flexible with multiple entry points output paths. So it's better to update your webpack config output field to the following one:

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  filename: "[name].js",
  publicPath: "/dist",
},
```

That will produce flat bundled chunks files structure like `./dist/main.js` and `./dist/main.css`.

#### css minification

To enable css minification you need to install [css-minimizer-webpack-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin/) (you can use any other minification plugin but I will just show example of using it) via `npm install --save-dev css-minimizer-webpack-plugin` or `yarn add -D css-minimizer-webpack-plugin`. And include it into your `webpack.config.js` file as following:

```
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
...
module.exports = {
...
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new CssMinimizerPlugin()],
  },
  plugins: [
    ...,
    new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
  ],
...
}
```

To make sure your css is minfified you just need to run webpack build and checkout bundled css file in dist directory. If it has no unnecessary spaces or lines wrap after legal comments that means you css is minified ;)

Comment: All is good _except_ for 2 things: The CSS is compiled in `dist/main.css` instead of `dist/css/main.css` and the JavaScript is compiled in `dist/main.js` instead of `dist/js/main.js`.

Comment: A I mentioned, webpack is not very flexible enough with multiple entry points. You can use two separated webpack configs for js and css, but do you really need so unique output files structure for that cost?

Comment: How about the `main.js` file, how do I minify it?

Comment: Use plugin for js minification, e.g. [Terser](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/terser-webpack-plugin/) or, if you want your application to bundle fast, use [esbuild-loader](https://github.com/privatenumber/esbuild-loader)